# How to use the max array

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, max

```
maxPrice = 0
    for item in cont["price_usd"]:
        if(item[1] > maxPrice):
           maxPrice = (item[1])

    print (maxPrice)
```

I'm trying to find the max price in an array, and I'm trying to use the max() method to make my code simpler. cont["price_usd"] is a list of [amount_coins, price] and I'm trying to compare all of the prices.

I tried doing this:

```
list = cont["price_usd"]:
max(list)
```

but I don't know how to express that I only want the second subitem in each item.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`map()`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html) and [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)

```
prices = list(map(lambda x: x[1], cont["price_usd"]))
maxPrice = max(prices)
print(maxPrice)
```

The `map` function here uses the lambda function `lambda x: x[1]` to take each element of `cont["price_usd"]`, extract the element at index `1`, and then put that into a list. Then we call `max` to find the largest value in that list.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `key` keyword of the [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function:

```
maxPrice = max(cont["price_usd"], key=lambda e: e[1])[1]
```